# Most important keyword search in Google without result

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, keywords

I have read some similar questions but could not find an appropriate answer.

The first two keywords (finca, Barbosa) for my site in Google Webmaster Tools keywords list are exactly what I expected. So far so good. When I use these keywords to search, I get no result for my site at all. I am not expecting a specific rank position, but there is no result at all.

I thought a combination of one keyword (finca, Barbosa) with another keyword in the list might give some results. The combination of these two words are more or less quiet specific searches so I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Google Webmaster Tools identifies keywords for your site, however, this has no connection with performance for those keywords. These listed keywords are site keywords (for the site overall) but SERPs (search engine result pages) return results for individual pages. It is a mistake to expect to perform well for keywords within this list because the list does not indicate performance (not all sites perform well for keywords found in GWT), but rather use it as a gauge to know what keywords Google recognizes for your site. Use Google Analytics to know how you are performing for any keyword.

As well, if your site is relatively new, it will take some months before any page will perform for the keywords recognized for that page. Also note that performance is on a page by page basis so your SEO efforts has to be focused on individual pages and less on the site overall.

If you want to start off with SEO, then I can recommend MarketSamurai. I use that and SEO PowerSuite which is not for beginners. MarketSamurai is somewhat affordable and really will help you get started. I also recommend reading MOZs http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo Beginners Guide to SEO. It is a great jumping off point! And it is free.

Answer (score 0):

After choosing the keyword you have to promote your keywords through off page optimization technique which is clearly mention by link scheme page. Follow all the steps in link scheme page and build quality and best links to your website. so that you can easily comes in search results.